# Update datagrid of Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is made from "Xamarin form DataGrid". When I renew/update the data content, I find that it does not follow to refresh. Is there anything I missed to do to make it refreshing? Any help would be appreciable.

BR,
Terry

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  There is very little useful information in your post that we could use to help you.  And as noted in your previous post, you need to specify which third party control you are using

Answer (score 0):

> When I renew/update the data content, I find that it does not follow
> to refresh.

Are you using nuget [Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid)?

You can recheck if you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for your item model.

For example, if you want UI refresh automatically once changing the value of property `Name`, you can do as follows:

```
public class Professional: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        //public string Name { get; set; }
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _name, value);
            }
        }
        public string Desigination { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string Experience { get; set; }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

And if you want UI refresh automatically once adding or remove item form the list of `ItemsSource`, you can define your the type of your datalist to `ObservableCollection<>`, for example:

```
  public ObservableCollection<Professional> Professionals {get;set;}
```